# Show columns placed in multiple ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Excel files with the following structure:

Each file has the exact same columns (Apples, Oranges, Bananas, etc.) but placed under different letters throughout the sheets. For example, column "Apples" is under letter A in the first 5 sheets, but it's under letter C in the rest of the sheets. This order is not consistent and varies in each file.

I would like a macro capable of:

1. Unwrap all the cells in all sheets.
2. Hide columns from A to Z in all sheets.
3. Unhide only three columns featuring the words "apples/apple", "oranges/orange" and "bananas/bananas" in row 1.
4. Shrink to fit the text in the "apples/apple" column and set the width to 120.
5. Wrap to fit the text on the "oranges/orange" and "bananas/bananas" columns and set the width to 350.
6. Zoom all sheets to 100%.

I have this macro that works like a charm, as it allows me to choose which three columns I want to keep. However, it works exclusively if they are placed in the exact same order in all sheets:

```
Sub AdjustTF()
ColumnWidth = 10
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim f As Boolean
Dim c As Long
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
' The following two lines are optional
Worksheets(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
For Each wsh In Worksheets
    wsh.Cells.WrapText = False
    wsh.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    wsh.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    wsh.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If f = False Then
        Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
            Prompt:="Select the columns to keep.", _
            Type:=8).EntireColumn
        f = True
    End If
    Set rng = wsh.Range(rng.Address).EntireColumn
    c = wsh.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(1, 1), wsh.Cells(1, c)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    With rng
        .Hidden = False
        With .Areas(1)
            .ColumnWidth = 3
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 120 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .ShrinkToFit = True
        End With
        With .Areas(2)
            .ColumnWidth = 8
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 350 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        With .Areas(3)
            .ColumnWidth = 8
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 350 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With
    wsh.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
NextSheet:
    Next wsh
    Application.Goto Worksheets(1).Range("A1"), True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case 424 ' Object required
            Resume NextSheet
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I've also this code, which is significantly lighter (even though doesn't quite perform all tasks I wanted) but for some reasons works only with a single file and not when assigned to my Personal.xls sheet.

```
Sub AdjustTFAlternate()
  Dim R As Range
  Dim Ws As Worksheet
  Dim Item
  'In each worksheet
  For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Hide all columns
    Ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    'Search for this words
    For Each Item In Array("apple*", "orange*", "banana*")
      'Search for a keyword in the 1st row
      Set R = Ws.Rows(1).Find(Item, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If R Is Nothing Then
        'Not found
        Exit For
      End If
      'Unhide this column
      R.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Trying to decode your module...what is the following code supposed to accomplish: `c = wsh.Cells.Find(What:="*",`?

Comment: Do you want a prompt for each sheet that is the workbook or do you want the macro to "remember" what Area(1), Area(2), and Area(3) are and automatically resize them in subsequent sheets?

Comment: Thanks Micheal for your quick answer and your code.
The fact is that I also noticed that the headers are actually not consistent, as sometimes is **apple** and some other times is **apples** for example. Would it be possible to indicate the text to look for in the headers of those 3 columns instead of manually select them? This way, all the columns including "apple" or "apples" will be shown. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error because the columns don't match?

Comment: Added a new popup if the column name isn't found exactly in subsequent worksheets.  Therefore, if you have **apple** in the first and second worksheet but **apples** in the third, you will receive a second `InputBox` when the code loops through to the third sheet and it cannot find **apples** exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much once again!
The formula is awesome, but the 2nd pop-up filters only the new 3 columns of 1 single sheet, instead of all the remaining ones. It pops up constantly until all the sheets are processed and I basically have to enter the same 3 columns each time.
I think the easier solution is to replace the column-selecting method by a simple keyword search. This way, I don't need to manually select any column and the function will simply unhide the columns containind "apple/apples", "Orange/oranges", etc. in their headers (row 1). What do you think?

Comment: Probably a good solution, but I would then change the input from a simple `InputBox` to an actual `UserForm1`, which falls outside the scope of the specific question.  How many sheets are in a typical worksheet?

Comment: Feel free to edit the formula as you like, the important thing is that 6 steps I mentioned in the first message are achieved, the method can vary. As per the sheets, I usually deal with files with at least 10 sheets.

Comment: The code is now updated to store previous choices in an array, so if on the first page you choose **apple** and then on the second page you choose **apples**, then on pages 3-n, the code will search for either **apple** or **apples**.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly. One more thing: do you know why the 100% zoom is only applied to one sheet instead of all? Also, I've got an alternative code which works differently and it's is significantly lighter (you can find the code in my first message), but it seems to filter only the first keyword and not all of them. Do you you think it would be a simpler solution?

Comment: It wasn't zooming because the `ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100` was in the wrong location...the code has been updated to achieve the proper zoom.  The alternative code does not achieve 1,3,5,6, so I would just use your original example.  It the answer works for you, please accept it (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want a popup box for the user to select the 3 columns on each sheet, remove the line that reads

```
f = True
```

that is inside the `If f = False Then` statement.

If you want the macro to "remember" the column headers for each column chosen on the first page, then you'll need to modify the code slightly (and make some assumptions):

Assumptions

1. The column headers are in the first row
2. The column headers are unique (i.e., you don't have the same column title multiple times in the same sheet).

EDIT: 
Code will now store all selected columns in an array that will search on each worksheet.  For example, if on worksheet 1 you have **apple**, **banana**, and **coconut**, you will get an initial `InputBox`.  If on worksheet 3, you now have **apples**, **bananas**, and **coconuts**, then you will get a second `InputBox` asking for these values.  Now, on worksheets 4-n, the code will search for *either* **apple** or **apples**.

Code

```
Sub AdjustTF()
ColumnWidth = 10
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim f As Boolean
Dim c As Long

'Dim aCol(1 To 1, 1 To 3) As String
Dim aCol() As String
    ReDim aCol(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
Dim iCol(1 To 3) As Integer
Dim iTemp As Integer
Dim uStr As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
' The following two lines are optional
Worksheets(1).Select
Range("A1").Select
For Each wsh In Worksheets
    d = 1
    wsh.Cells.WrapText = False
    wsh.Cells.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    wsh.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    wsh.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    If f = False Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Err.Number = 0
            Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                Prompt:="Select the columns to keep.", _
                Type:=8).EntireColumn
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        f = True
        aCol(1, 1) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(1).Column).Value
        aCol(2, 1) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(2).Column).Value
        aCol(3, 1) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(3).Column).Value

    Else
        On Error Resume Next
            For a = 1 To 3
                iCol(a) = 0
            Next
            For a = 1 To UBound(aCol, 2)
                Err.Number = 0
                iTemp = wsh.Cells.Find(what:=aCol(1, a), lookat:=xlWhole).Column
                    If Err.Number = 0 And iCol(1) = 0 Then iCol(1) = iTemp
                Err.Number = 0
                iTemp = wsh.Cells.Find(what:=aCol(2, a), lookat:=xlWhole).Column
                    If Err.Number = 0 And iCol(2) = 0 Then iCol(2) = iTemp
                Err.Number = 0
                iTemp = wsh.Cells.Find(what:=aCol(3, a), lookat:=xlWhole).Column
                    If Err.Number = 0 And iCol(3) = 0 Then iCol(3) = iTemp

                If iCol(1) > 0 And iCol(2) > 0 And iCol(3) > 0 Then Exit For
            Next
            If iCol(1) = 0 Or iCol(2) = 0 Or iCol(3) = 0 Then
                wsh.Activate
                    Err.Number = 0
                    Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
                        Prompt:="Select the columns to keep.", _
                        Type:=8).EntireColumn
                    If Err.Number > 0 Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If


                a = UBound(aCol, 2) + 1
                ReDim Preserve aCol(1 To 3, 1 To a)
                aCol(1, a) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(1).Column).Value
                aCol(2, a) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(2).Column).Value
                aCol(3, a) = wsh.Cells(1, rng.Areas(3).Column).Value

            Else
                uStr = Range(wsh.Cells(1, iCol(1)), wsh.Cells(1, iCol(1))).Address & "," & _
                    Range(wsh.Cells(1, iCol(2)), wsh.Cells(1, iCol(2))).Address & "," & _
                    Range(wsh.Cells(1, iCol(3)), wsh.Cells(1, iCol(3))).Address


                Set rng = Range(uStr)
            End If
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    End If

    Set rng = wsh.Range(rng.Address).EntireColumn


    c = wsh.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(1, 1), wsh.Cells(1, c)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    With rng
        .Hidden = False
        With .Areas(1)
            .ColumnWidth = 3
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 120 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .ShrinkToFit = True
        End With
        With .Areas(2)
            .ColumnWidth = 8
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 350 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        With .Areas(3)
            .ColumnWidth = 8
            For i = 1 To 3
                .ColumnWidth = 350 / .Width * .ColumnWidth
            Next i
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With
    wsh.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    wsh.Activate
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    wsh.Cells(1, 1).Select
NextSheet:
    Next wsh
    Application.Goto Worksheets(1).Range("A1"), True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case 424 ' Object required
            Resume NextSheet
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    End Select
End Sub
```